# Getting KeyError when accessing third column of CSV using DictReader

Tags: python, csv

I try to use Python to sort a csv file by date (newest entries first). The column of the csv file that contains dates is the third column of the csv file.

When I run the code below, I get the following error message:

> KeyError: 2

Could you please provide me guidelines to correct my script below:

```
import csv
import os
from csv import writer
from datetime import datetime

with open("data.csv", newline="") as csvfile:
spamreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
sortedlist = sorted(spamreader, key=lambda row: datetime.strptime(row[2]), reverse=False)

with open("sortdata.csv", "w") as f:
    fieldnames = ["detection_date"]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in sortedlist:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: `DictReader` gives you a dictionary for each row, you need to access it with the column headers as keys, not with integer indexing.

Comment: If you want to access the rows as tuples, you should not use `DictReader`.

Comment: Does your csv file have a header row? Can you post a sample of it with 2-3 lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reading the error, `keyerror: 2`, my eye goes to , `datetime.strptime(row[2])`.

You're trying to use a 0-based *column index number* for a DictReader, which expects a *column name* (which is derived from the first line (row) of data in your file, which it expects to be a "header").

So, swap `row[2]` out for `row['third_column_name']` and you should be good.

If you don't have a header, use `csv.reader()`.

Comment: Many thanks for your comments that allowed me to correct my Python script :)

Comment: @mollieda, if this helped, please accept (the checkmark), and if you like, vote it up, too :)